# Minimum with conditions x [1] + x [2] = 1 [r] optim

Tags: r

```r
#attempt
optim(c(0.1,0.1),
      function(x){x[1]^2*0.05126875+2*((x[1]*x[2])*-0.00809375)+x[2]^2*0.03376875})
```

How to create a function that generates values ​​from 0.01 to 1 for x [1] and x [2], and returns me what was the lowest result with the condition of x [1] + x [2] = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a constrain and still want to use `optim`, you can reformulate your constrained optimization problem, e.g.,

```
optim(0.1, 
      function(x) x^2*0.05126875+2*((x*(1-x))*-0.00809375)+(1-x)^2*0.03376875, 
      lower = 0,
      upper = 1,
      method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

which gives

```
$par
[1] 0.4135589

$value
[1] 0.01645614

$counts
function gradient
       4        4

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

For your case, the solution is

```
x1 = 0.4135589
x2 = 1-x1
x = c(x1,x2)

> x
[1] 0.4135589 0.5864411
```